# ANOVA and dependence WITHIN a group

Tags: anova, independence, cross-correlation

I have three different methods that I would like to compare using ANOVA. The variable to compare is method accuracy that I get trough cross-validation. This means that the same data set (N=60 subjects) is divided into training and test sets, and into placebo and treatment groups (every subject has taken part to both placebo and treatment group), and the accuracy of each three methods are calculated several times (e.g. 100 or 500 cross-validation rounds).

The three methods are dependent because of the same training and test sets at each round, and therefore I'm using repeated measures design. However, what should I do with the fact that the accuracies are dependent also WITHIN the groups? For example, if I choose 500 rounds in my cross-validation, I have smaller p-values than with 100 rounds.

If the within group dependency cannot be taken into account, is there another way to determine which method has the highest accuracy?

ps. I also have another factor in the ANOVA, but didn't want to complicate things..